# Drill into steel frame for cargo rack

Tags: frames, rack, cargo

So I have a bike without pegs for the mounting of a cargo bike rack.

It is a steel frame so I was thinking of installing make-shift pegs myself.

Is this going to breach the integrity of the frame?

I know some types of metals and constructions aren't intended to be drilled through.

Comment: It really depends where and how large the hole is. It might help if you posted a photo of the area and told us the size of the hole. But even then it’s hard for anonymous internet commentators to give a definitive answer and it might be best for you to ask the manufacturer (who will, for liability reasons, most likely say that it’s a bad idea).

Comment: There are various clamp-on arrangements you can use, from simple P clips to specially designed racks. Would any of those work?

Comment: You *might* be OK, but you might not.   Try some clamp-based scheme first.

Comment: If clamps do not work, a brase on bracket would be better than drilling.

Answer (score 3):

It mostly depends on the thickness of the tube.

Chainstays and seat stays tend to be quite small tube, so drilling them takes a larger percentage of metal away.  I would not drill a stay unless I had a welder to add metal- instead I'd use a clamp-on fitting.

For downtubes and seat tubes, the tube itself tends to be wider.  I've successfully used a **nutsert** or **rivnut** to add bidon mounts to a steel road bike.  This involved careful drilling, then using a special tool to mount and crimp a special insert into the frame.

Comment: Here's a more complete Q&A for the thicker tubes.   https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/52207/19705