# Bottle holder for mountain bike

Tags: bottle

I want to get a bottle holder for my bike.

It has no pre-drilled holes for the holder.

I found some that clamp on but not sure if they would work with the wide tube that I would need to mount it to.

[image]

Comment: Would it be an option for you to use a hydration back pack instead?

Comment: cable ties - do the job just grand, although not for professional level racers, asthey will snap given enough force :-)

Comment: Use a clamp-on cage:  https://www.google.com/search?q=clamp+on+water+bottle+cage

Comment: The universal clamp on variety should work just fine, they are made for the down tube which is generally large in size, just make sure the zip ties or straps do not interfere with the cable that runs on the underside in the image. They also make handle bar mounted cages as well if you have room, although they are not fun to take to the chest in an over the bar type of crash.

Comment: @Old Nick Hydration back pack is an option. As it's already in the 90's, one bottle probably would not be enough.

Comment: The handyman's secret weapon: DUCT TAPE!!!

Comment: One solution for a steel frame is documented here   https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52207/   (not a dupe)  and drilling holes in your frame is potentially risky.

Comment: The top tube intrigues me. How is the pump clamp attached? It looks as if it uses bottle cage holes. Could we get a picture of that?

Comment: @Carel great spotting - they look like machine screws with combo philips/flat drives.  So not a normal bike bolt and definitely not in the usual place.  I'm suspicious someone's just whacked them into the frame.

Comment: @Criggie : The reason I wanted a close-up on that spot. It's difficult to judge from the angle the picture seems to have been taken.

Answer (score 4):

Get a clamp-on solution like the SKS Anywhere, Topeak VersaMount or Elite VIP.

As Nate W pointed out in the comments, make sure it doesn’t interfere with your cables.
[image]
[image]

A quick and dirty solution with cable ties and duct tape can work temporarily as well.

There are also bottle cage mounts which clamp to the saddle’s rails, for example the TacX Saddle Clamp:
[image]

I think a disadvantage of this solution is that you can’t slide behind the saddle on descents. They are primarily intended for time trial bikes.

Comment: Behind the saddle solutions tend to fare badly on a mountain bike as they are prone to the bottles being bounced out.

Comment: Thanks for all the ideas. I ordered one of these. https://www.amazon.com/Lumintrail-Handlebar-Adapter-Lightweight-Aluminum/dp/B01LYSVW0P/ref=sr_1_2_sspa?keywords=Handlebar+Bottle+Cage+Holder&qid=1558371859&s=sporting-goods&sr=1-2-spons&psc=1

Comment: @fixit7 . But fit them at the front side of the bars, not at the rear side as the pictures suggest. Also be aware that they might affect the handling of the bike especially with full bottles.

Comment: The problem with the front of the bars is that that’s where the cables are. I think taking the bottle out without causing unwanted bar movement can also be surprisingly hard.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of options here:

- Use a hydration pack on your back
- Use a hydration pack in a framebag
- Use a feedbag attached to the handlebars to hold a waterbottle

Get creative! There's lots more ways to carry water out on the trail.

Clamps, drilling, etc into the frame are probably not the best idea for maintaining the integrity of the frame and security of the bottle.

Comment: Except that it's pretty regular for companies to drill holes in frames and install threaded rivets on many models of bikes.

Answer (score 2):

Using a strap on cage would likely be the easiest method.  You should be able to ask a question of the manufacturer and get strap lengths to compare to your tube circumference and determine fit.  It's quite common for bikes to have very large downtubes and I imagine it's common for strap on kits to come with longer than necessary straps, since they can usually be trimmed.

You could also get a quote at a shop to get holes drilled in the frame and threaded rivets installed and mount a cage.  More info [here](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52207/how-to-fit-rivnut-nutsert-to-frame).  I've done this on both bikes that came with no mounts and as a fix on bikes where the threaded rivets from the factory became stripped (after drilling out the stripped factory rivets).  This might be more expensive up front (labor from a shop) but allow you to use a much less expensive cage.

Comment: I went with this. https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01LYSVW0P?ref=ppx_pt2_dt_b_prod_image

Comment: You are now "over nine thousand"  Well done!

Comment: @Criggie What is "over 9 thousand"?

Comment: @fixit7it was Deleted User's point score yesterday, but there was some cleanup event overnight and many of the long-term users lost some points,   "over 9000" is also a meme I learned from my kids  https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/its-over-9000  Anything further, please take to [chat]